# Can url contain # and some variable at the same time

Tags: php, url

I would like to send in url a variable and at the same time #menu to provide that page will appear at certain place. I want to use GET method only if it's possible. I hope it makes sense and thank you for help.

```
header("Location: ../index.php?change=succ#menu");
```

this way works the variable but the #menu doesn't (page is loaded at the top) and yes I set...< div id=menu>

Comment: _..but the #menu doesn't ..._ It works for me

Comment: You're code should work. Sounds like a problem on the target page for me. Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754126/php-header-location-redirect-to-url-with-html-anchor Maybe you're div has a wrong styling, is broken because of a typo or you use the id multiple times?!

Comment: You're right..There is gonna be some other problem because it doesn't work without the variable either

Comment: problem solved...I just changed the name of id and now it works perfectly