# Make header('location: ..\ ') To Current Scroll Spot on Page

Tags: php

I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to find an answer to this. Basically, I'm trying to make  **header('location: ..\  ')** redirect me to the **current page** as well as the **current scroll spot** on the page.

Getting a redirect to the current page is easy, however, I can't seem to have it redirect me to a specific spot on the page.

I can redirect to specific spot using something like **home**. However, this doesn't work because I have 20 different items with buttons, and depending on which item is clicked, the page should redirect to that item. Therefore, something like **home** won't work.

I've also been experimenting with Javascript and JQuery but the reason that can't work is because my scripts in PHP and the redirect much happen through that (right?).

I'm still learning PHP so please go easy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Redirect can happen via JS too. `window.location.html = '...'`

Comment: can you show us some code?

Comment: You can redirect then have JS execute on load.

Comment: You could use anchor tag with hash in your url to jump to an certain element in your HTML.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754126/php-header-location-redirect-to-url-with-html-anchor/30754564 would help you

Answer (score 4):

If you are setting anchor with id, in your HTML, you can easily jump to that from an hash in the url.

```
<!-- ... -->
<a id="someSectionToJumpTo></a>
<!-- ... -->
```

and then in your url, you would go to

```
https://example.com/your/page#someSectionToJumpTo
```

this will jump directly to the anchor.

Note that there will not be any scroll animation.

This can be changed from your PHP aswell.

```
header('location: ..\#someSectionToJumpTo')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I cannot do this. The reason is because I have a single PHP script that redirects 20 button clicks. And I need each button click redirect to the scroll spot where the button is located.